# Как отправить сообщение через VK API Python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

не могу понять почему не могу отправить сообщение, дело в правах доступа или авторизации, выдает одну и ту же ошибку, благодарен за ответ
[image: 1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Теоретически, у вас к аккаунту ВК подключена двухфакторная авторизация, и авторизацию нужно производить как-то по-особенному.

Comment: Желательно, приводите код и текста ошибок не на скриншотах.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в авторизации.

Выдержка из документации:

> Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в [Standalone-приложении](https://vk.com/dev/standalone) через [Implicit Flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user). Требуются [права доступа](https://vk.com/dev/permissions): **messages**.

Скорее всего, Вы забыли выполнить или выполнили неправильно [это](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user).

Вообще для таких целей посоветую Вам модуль `vk_api`.

Answer (score 0):

**Попробуй получить отсюда токен, и через токен отправить сообщение.** [https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=ЛОГИН&password=ПАРОЛЬ](https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%9D&password=%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%AC)

**После отправляем запрос:**
[https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?&user_id=АЙДИПОЛУЧАТЕЛЯ&random_id=РАНДОМНОЕЧИСЛО&message=СООБЩЕНИЕ(БЕЗ_ВСЯКИХ_КОВЫЧЕК)&v=5.95&access_token=ТОКЕН](https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?&user_id=%D0%90%D0%99%D0%94%D0%98%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%A3%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AF&random_id=%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%95%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%9E&message=%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%A9%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95(%D0%91%D0%95%D0%97_%D0%92%D0%A1%D0%AF%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%A5_%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%9A)&v=5.95&access_token=%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D)